# Trouble passing @include('includes.categories') in other blade file Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

So im busy on my first laravel project.
Now i edited my question.

Anyway, i have my navbar that is visible on all pages.
However i also want my /resources/views/master/search.blade.php
and my
/resources/views/includes/categories.blade.php
visible on all pages for auth users.

What is the best approach for this?
tried a lot of stuff also tried using the
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views
method to no avail.

my latest try was to use the @include on different pages.

Now trying it on the page wishlist.blade.php with the categories.blade.php that has a @include itself to subcategories.blade.php

```
@extends('master.profile')
@section('title', 'Wishlist')
@section('profile-content')
    @include('includes.flash.success')
    @include('includes.flash.error')
    @include('includes.categories', ['categories' => 'categories'])
```

this gives me the error : "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
<?php $__currentLoopData = $categories; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $cat): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" style="list-style: none;">
        <a class="btn-dark btn-sm text-white" href="<?php echo e(route('category.show', $cat)); ?>" class="dropdown-item list-group-item-action list-inline-item" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><?php if(isset($category) && $cat -> isAncestorOf(optional($category))): ?>
            <?php endif; ?><small><?php echo e($cat -> name); ?></small></a>
        <?php if($cat -> children -> isNotEmpty()): ?>
            <span class="btn-info btn-sm text-white"><?php echo e($cat -> num_products); ?></span>
 
            <ul class="dropdown-menu-2 text-white" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
 
                <?php echo $__env->make('includes.subcategories', ['categories' => $cat -> children], \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
 
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
```

Any advice appreciated.

beginner here

---

In the meantime i tried to define a variable (please mind i am a beginner so even that is not working for me.)
I don't know if i need to do this in a controller or?

Also i tried everything regarding the View sharing item.
Also did not work out, whatever i tried.

The only thing i want is to have 2 blade files to be represented on all my pages in my project under my navbar.
Because these 2 blade files complete my navbar as 1 whole.
navbar (this one is on all pages)
search ( this one is only on the main page and category pages)
categories ( same as above)

One i go to any other page its just the navbar.
How can is solve this the easy way.

---

This is what i am now trying to get the category navbar represented on all pages now.
Im adding the @include to my main.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">


    @hasSection('title')
        <title>{{config('app.name')}} - @yield('title')</title>
    @else
        <title>{{config('app.name')}}</title>
    @endif
</head>
<body class="pb-4">
@auth
@include('master.navbar')
@include('master.search')
@include('includes.categories', ['categories' => $category])

@endauth


            @yield('content')

@include('master.footer')


</body>
</html>
```

And this is the error i am getting :

Undefined variable: category

```
<?php if (! empty(trim($__env->yieldContent('title')))): ?>
        <title><?php echo e(config('app.name')); ?> - <?php echo $__env->yieldContent('title'); ?></title>
    <?php else: ?>
        <title><?php echo e(config('app.name')); ?></title>
    <?php endif; ?>
</head>
<body class="pb-4">
<?php if(auth()->guard()->check()): ?>
<?php echo $__env->make('master.navbar', \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
<?php echo $__env->make('master.search', \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
<?php echo $__env->make('includes.categories', ['categories' => $category], \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
 
<?php endif; ?>
 
 
            <?php echo $__env->yieldContent('content'); ?>
 
<?php echo $__env->make('master.footer', \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

this are the blade files used to get the categories navbar : /includes/categories.blade.php

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar profile-bg-carbon justify-content-around">

     @include('includes.subcategories', ['categories' => $categories])

</nav>
</div>
```

and /includes/subcategories.blade.php :

```
@foreach($categories as $cat)
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" style="list-style: none;">
        <a class="btn-dark btn-sm text-white" href="{{ route('category.show', $cat) }}" class="dropdown-item list-group-item-action list-inline-item" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">@if(isset($category) && $cat -> isAncestorOf(optional($category)))
            @endif<small>{{ $cat -> name }}</small></a>
        @if($cat -> children -> isNotEmpty())
            <span class="btn-info btn-sm text-white">{{ $cat -> num_products }}</span>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu-2 text-white" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">

                @include('includes.subcategories', ['categories' => $cat -> children])

            </ul>
        @endif
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Here is the \App\Category Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Traits\Uuids;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use Uuids;
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $keyType = 'string';


    /**
     * Returns collection of root categories
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public static function roots()
    {
        return self::whereNull('parent_id') -> get();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the collection of all categories A-Z ordered
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public static function nameOrdered()
    {
        return self::orderBy('name') -> get();
    }


    /**
     * @return \App\Category parent category, null for root category
     */
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this -> hasOne(self::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function parents()
    {
        $ancestorsCollection = collect();
        $currentParent = $this -> parent;
        while($currentParent != null){
            $ancestorsCollection -> push($currentParent);
            $currentParent = $currentParent -> parent;
        }

        return $ancestorsCollection -> reverse();
    }

    /**
     * @return collection of category's children
     */
    public function getChildrenAttribute()
    {
        return self::where('parent_id', $this -> id) -> get();
    }

    /**
     * Relationship with products
     *
     * @return collection of \App\Product that belongs to this category
     */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this -> hasMany(\App\Product::class, 'category_id', 'id')
            -> where('active', true);
    }

    /**
     * @var \App\Category $childCategory
     * @return boolean, true if this category is ancestor of $childCategory
     */
    public function isAncestorOf($childCategory)
    {
        if(is_null($childCategory)) return false;
        // starting from parent of the child category
        $tempCategory = $childCategory;

        // while is not root
        while($tempCategory){
            // true, if tempCategory equals this category
            if($tempCategory -> id == $this -> id)
                return true;
            $tempCategory = $tempCategory -> parent;
        }
        // otherwise $this is not ancestor
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return int num products this cateogy and all subcategories sumed up
     */
    public function getNumProductsAttribute()
    {
        $numProducts = count($this -> products);

        $otherCategories = Category::where('id', '<>', $this -> id) -> get();
        foreach($otherCategories as $categ){
            if($this -> isAncestorOf($categ))
                $numProducts += count($categ -> products);
        }

        return $numProducts;
    }

    /**
     * Returns collection of all ancestors, gets the recursivly
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function allChildren()
    {
        // get all children
        $children = $this -> children;
        // foreach child category call recursivly
        foreach ($this -> children as $childCategory){
            $children = $children-> merge($childCategory -> allChildren());
        }
        return $children;
    }

    /**
     * Array of all subcategories ids
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function allChildrenIds() : array
    {
        return $this -> allChildren() -> pluck('id') -> toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Array of all subcategories names
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function allChildrenNames() : array
    {
        return $this -> allChildren() -> pluck('name') -> toArray();
    }


    /**
     * Returns paginated collection of products of this category and all children categories
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function childProducts()
    {
        $allAcceptedCategoriesIds = array_merge([$this -> id], $this -> allChildrenIds());

        return Product::where('active', true) -> whereIn('category_id', $allAcceptedCategoriesIds) -> orderByDesc('created_at')
            -> paginate(config('market.products_per_page'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error is pretty clear; your `categories.blade.php` is referencing a variable called `$categories`, but you don't provide it. If you're going to `@include()` something that requires a variable, make sure it's defined in the view that is `@include()`ing it, or pass an Empty variable like `@include('includes.categories', ['categories' => collect()])` (or `null`, etc)

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you so much i did add the line as you said and was able to load the page.
However it did not show nothing aside from some background styling from the cat menu.
Then i looked closed and noticed that in the /includes/categories.blade.php had this code :

<div class="container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar profile-bg-carbon justify-content-around">

     @include('includes.subcategories', ['categories' => $categories])

</nav>
</div>

Comment: Yeah, it's likely blank as `$categories` is now an empty Collection, so if for example you have an `@foreach($categories as $category)` in your `subcategories.blade.php`, nothing in that block will render. Instead of `['categories' => collect()])`, you'd have to define _something_ to pass forward.

Comment: this is the sub

Comment: @foreach($categories as $cat)
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" style="list-style: none;">
        <a class="btn-dark btn-sm text-white" href="{{ route('category.show', $cat) }}" class="dropdown-item list-group-item-action list-inline-item" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">@if(isset($category) && $cat -> isAncestorOf(optional($category)))
            @endif<small>{{ $cat -> name }}</small></a>
        @if($cat -> children -> isNotEmpty())
            <span class="btn-info btn-sm text-white">{{ $cat -> num_products }}</span>

Comment: <ul class="dropdown-menu-2 text-white" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">

                @include('includes.subcategories', ['categories' => $cat -> children])

Comment: So yes, if `$categories` is empty, which it will be if you do `['categories' => collect()]`, nothing in that block of code will run. You need to define some way to populate `$categories`. Also, please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69167105/edit) instead of posting in the comments 

Comment: and then </ul>@endif</li>@endforeach

Comment: Ok thanks Tim, im new here just need to figure it out :)

Comment: No worries! It's just a lot harder to read all of that in the comments (most of it is unnecessary as well, just the presence of `@foreach(...)` being important)

Comment: Also, read this part of the documentation; it's a section on how to pass data (like `$categories`) to a certain view and have it available everywhere, which is quite useful if you're `@including` that view in multiple parts of your code: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Comment: Yes now its giving me this error : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Yes i already did read that part about laravel then tried to apply that technique but to no luck.... really one of these days. lol

Comment: That error generally means that `$categories` is `null`, or otherwise not an Iterable (like an Array or Collection). And yeah, it's a bit more advanced of a concept. Can you edit your question to include your attempt using that approach? Will be much easier to help you debug it.

Comment: Done hope it looks better

Comment: That's an issue: `['categories' => 'categories']`, you're passing the `string` `'categories'`, and `@foreach('categories' as $cat)` is triggering that error. You can't do a `foreach` on a `string` like that. Should be `['categories' => $categories]` (assuming you defined `$categories` somewhere)

Comment: Yes now im back at the undefined variable when changing to $categories

Comment: That's what the last half of my comment means - *"(assuming you defined $categories somewhere)"* - You haven't, but that's what the documentation shows how to do, and ultimately what you'll need to implement.

Comment: tried everything....

Comment: Never had so much trouble getting something done.

Comment: I don't see any updates to your question with what you've tried... Until you do that, I can't really help anymore, sorry 

Comment: Updated with what im trying to accomplish

Comment: I 100% meant you need to include the code that you've attempted to use, not a re-worded description of what you're trying to accomplish. I'm clear on that, what I'm not clear on is why you keep saying "it didn't work", but then don't show your code or explain more what that means. "it didn't work" is pretty useless as a statement; why didn't it work? What were you expecting vs what actually happened? Were there any errors? Please provide more details or, as I keep saying, I won't be able to help anymore.

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding and thanks for your patience.
i have updated the post now hope somebody can point me in the right direction now and that its clear enough.

Comment: Much better, thank you   But, I still don't see where you've defined `$category` (and that should be `$categories`). Did you try with `View::share('key', 'value');`, or with a `ViewComposer` as shown in the documentation? That's really going to be the only way to make this work as you've described it... It would be something like `View::share('categories', Category::all())` (if you have a Model for `Category`, or `DB::table('categories')->get()` if you don't). That _should_ make `$categories` available everywhere.

Comment: Well the View::share('key', 'value'); i tried it but im nearly sure i did it wrong as i entered :

View::share('includes.categories') and im positive that i wrong. i really feel like a moron here but i want to learn :)

Comment: Yup, it expects 2 parameters, the `key` is what the variable will be called, i.e. `'categories'` would translate to `$categories`. The 2nd parameter is the actual content of the variable, so `Category::all()` if you have a model, or `DB::table('categories')->get()` if you don't (but you should use a Model if possible). So, `View::share('categories', Category::all())` or `View::share('categories', DB::table('categories')->get())`

Comment: i have a model in \App that is called category i will add it now to the post

Comment: Make sure to follow naming conventions; PHP class names are `StudlyCase` (each word is capitalized, no spaces/underscores/hyphens/etc.), so it should be `class Category extends Model`, in `Category.php` file. Edit: It is, perfect 

Comment: just added the model to the post that i have

Comment: any more ideas?

Comment: I've already posted what I think is the solution, did you even attempt it? At a certain point, you're going to have to start debugging this on your own... I can point you in the right direction, but ultimately you'll have to figure out what you're doing and why things aren't working...

Comment: Thanks im a step further and its showing on all pages.
However now the dropdown class is expanded on all pages if you understand me it all dropdown content is shown... but getting htere

Comment: Sounds like a separate issue. I'd add an answer below (you can answer your own questions) and include all the code you used to accomplish this, then maybe step away for a bit and try to figure it out on your own. If you still get stuck with something, ask a new question.

Comment: got i working thanks

Answer (score -1):

this solved the issue

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('categories', (new \App\Category)->roots());

    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        if ($this->app->environment() !== 'production') {
            $this->app->register(\Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).